# I have this error: _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ProveedorModel>')

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

This is my code:

```
class ProveedoresService{
  final _dio = new Dio();
  Future<List<ProveedorModel>> getProveedorByName() async{
    final resp = await _dio.get(url);
    final List<ProveedorModel> proveedorList = resp.data;    //HERE MARKS MY ERROR....
    return proveedorList.map(
      (obj) => ProveedorModel.fromJson(obj)
      ).toList();
  }
}
```

And I am getting the error is:

> _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List')

Comment: `resp.data` is actually a `Map`, and not a `List`, so you'll need to convert it. This seems to be a JSON, so probably you want to do `resp.data["some_key"]`.

Comment: Could you share, how does the ```resp.data``` looks like? Just like Enzo said, it is a map you can not store it into a list that to a type specifice one.

Answer (score 1):

The data coming from the API is not equivalent to `List<ProveedorModel>`.

Probably it is a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

So, your `resp.data` has a data type of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

Now to convert `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` to `List<ProveedorModel>` you have to create a `fromMap` function in the model class.

**Example**

```
class ProvModel {
    final String name;
    final int age;
    const ProvModel({this.name, this.age});
    
    // From Map function
    factory ProvModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
        // API:
        // [
        //     {
        //         'name_field': "Alex",
        //         'age_field': 20,
        //     },
        // ]

        return ProvModel(
            name: data['name_field'], 
            age: data['age_field'], 
        );
    }
}
```

Now you have to convert each and every element of `resp.data` into a `ProvModel` and add to the returning list.

```
class ProvService {
  final _dio = new Dio();

  Future<List<ProvModel>> getProvByName() async {
    final resp = await _dio.get(url);

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = resp.data;
    final List<ProvModel> provList = [];

    for (Map<String, dynamic> data in list) {

      // Converting each and every element form Map<String, dynamic> to ProvModel
      final ProvModel provModel = ProvModel.fromMap(data);

      provList.add(provModel);
    }

    return provList;
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve your given error.

If you have any doubt comment it.